# Geography of Malini river

Tags: mahabharata, india, rivers, geography

A river named Malini is mentioned in the Adi parva of [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm).

> And they then passed a long time there in each other's company. And
> sporting with each other, just as they pleased, for a long time as if
> it were only a single day, the Rishi begat on Menaka a daughter named
> Sakuntala. And Menaka (as her conception advanced) went to the banks
> of the **river Malini** coursing along a valley of the charming mountains
> of Himavat. And there she gave birth to that daughter.

Is it extant? If not, then what is the current name of location where Malini river flown?

Answer (score 3):

The shloka  mentioned in the question is as follows.

> प्रस्थे हिमवतो रम्ये मालिनीमभितोनदीम्  |
>   जातमुत्युज्य तं गर्भ मेनका मालिनीमनु'॥

[**Malini**](http://kanvashram.org/about.php) is the river originating  in Shivalika mountain range in the state of Uttarakhand (India) and is flowing through Uttar Pradesh merge with holy river Ganga flowing through cities Bijnor and Najibabad . Actually there are three rivers of similar names flowing side by side called as Milini , Malin and Malini. River Malini branches out from Malin river and merge in  Milini river , the in between flow of the water is known as Malini river.

---

Here is the Hindi Information about [**Malini River**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZMQXBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT3&lpg=PT3&dq=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%80%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80&source=bl&ots=O4XQk7JO5E&sig=ACfU3U06DaeriJJVOVxeCJ7HYnjceD-UjA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3prjmqrDkAhWVX3wKHVtHD4Q4HhDoATACegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%80%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80&f=false)

---

In Hinduism scriptures besides Mahabharata Malini river is also mentioned in [**Valimiki Ramayana**](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga68/ayodhya_68_frame.htm) -Book II : Ayodhya Kanda -Sarga  68- Shloka 12. Where its location is also mentioned .

> न्यन्तेनापरतालस्य प्रलम्बस्योत्तरम् प्रति |
>   निषेवमाणास्ते जग्मुर्नदीम् मध्येन मालिनीम् || 2.68.12 ||
>
> Those messengers went on touching Malini River, flowing between the passing Aparatala Mountain and the northern end of Pralamba Mountain.

In his book [**History Of Ancient India (a Neriver  Version) : From 7300 Bb To 4250 Bc**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=b7gOBW8oDFgC&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=malaini%20river%20disappearing&source=bl&ots=JvMf9Z16mF&sig=ACfU3U0oE3MeuxMD_4B1gZ5yJ3Ruif1U8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEusvzlbDkAhX07XMBHYMYBRAQ6AEwHHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=malaini%20river%20disappearing&f=false) , author J.P. Mitta mentions that the  Malini is known now as Ramganga.

> The river malini after rising from Gharwal hills flowed towards the
>   west of Najibabad in district Bijnor of U.P. and then met the river
>   Ganga . The river Malini is known as Ramganga.

---

As reported in this [**News 18 article**](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=hi&u=https://hindi.news18.com/news/uttarakhand/dehradun-malini-river-is-getting-extinct-of-uttarakhand-970045.html&prev=search)  -  April 2017 . River Malini is getting extinct now a days , most probably because of climate change , drying due to reduced base flows and heavy extraction.

---

And finally  as your inquiry about its current location , here is [**Google Map of current Malini river**](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kanvashram.%E2%80%9D+Birth+Place+of+Emperor+Bharat+%E2%80%9C/@29.7924046,78.4485303,6998m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x390965271842b213:0x74ca34785f95fa60!8m2!3d29.7926781!4d78.4593047) , where we can trace the precise location of river and the  kanva Muni Ashram by navigating on map.  At Kanva Ashrama the river is known as Milini and the Malin river then one branch of Malin river is called as Malini river . The river seems to be getting smaller as it flows and merges with some other river named Milini.

Comment: It looks like Milini is the original name of the river , but in between it is called as Malini. There is very less info. avaliable on river malini on the internert, But seems that current Malini river is a small branch of Milini river. And two are the same.